# Update By Query to update multiple fields at a time in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a use case of update by query in elastic search.

I am keeping a doc like -

```
"a" : "1",
"b" : "2",
"version1" : 456
"c" : {
   "version2" : 123,
   "d" : "3"
}
```

Now dependently for my use case-

1. I either want to update field a, b and version1
2. Or I will update field d and version2.

I got partial answer in [Update By Query in Elasticsearch using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038887/update-by-query-in-elasticsearch-using-java).

I am trying things like this-

```
    BulkIndexByScrollResponse r = ubqrb.script(script)
        .script(script1)
        .script(script2)
        .script(script3)
        .script(script4)
        .filter(qb).get();
```

However `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` doesn't allow me to give multiple scripts and only and last one, ie `script4` is used and rest are neglected.

I also tried -

```
    Script script4 = new Script("ctx._source.a=\"abc\",b=\"xyz\"");
```

However this one also failed.

Any idea what can be done using update by where.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
new Script("ctx._source.a=\"abc\"; ctx._source.b=\"xyz\"");
```