# NPE while executing Update By Query in Elasticsearch using Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.4 in a Spring Boot application and I need to execute [`_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html) request to the remote ES instance using Java API.
I've found the way to accomplish this task at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37042003/4806529), but as for my case I've got an NPE trying to execute the `.get()` function.

A module for ES included:

```
compile 'org.elasticsearch.module:reindex:2.4.1'
```

Here's a code snippet I use for testing right now:

```
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder request = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(clientWrapper.getClient());  // clientWrapper is a bean and gets injected
Script script = new Script(
  "ctx._source.testName = \"TEST HAPPENED\"",
  ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE, null, null);

request.source().setTypes("type");

BulkIndexByScrollResponse r = request
  .source(ES_INDEX_NAME)
  .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("testId", "Sk9lzQHdJT0"))
  .script(script)
  .get();  // the exception gets raised here
```

Here's a wrapped `Client` bean:

```
@Bean
public ClientWrapper elasticsearchClient(Client client) {
return new ClientWrapper(
  TransportClient.builder()
    .addPlugin(ReindexPlugin.class)  // here's the plugin that is supposed to work
    .settings(client.settings())
    .build());
}
```

Wrapper is needed to allow configuring via Spring Boot configuration files, so it's just for convenience.

The `NullPointerException` is caused by invoking the `execute(...)` method of the 
`TransportProxyClient`:

```
final TransportActionNodeProxy<Request, Response> proxy = proxies.get(action);  // no proxy found here
... 
proxy.execute(node, request, listener);  // NPE here
```

I wonder if I missed some step or maybe the usage has changed since the question mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing config for transport information. It should be
`TransportClient.builder().addPlugin(ReindexPlugin.class)
    .build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
        InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));`

Comment: What version of elasticsearch and reindex are you using, please? I get the error "`TransportClient.builder()` cannot be resolved".

Comment: I am using ES 2.xx

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just a hint for those who'd use version `5.5.0` or similar: The plugin has to be added as a second parameter in  `PreBuiltTransportClient`'s constructor.